# Открытие ссылки по шаблону

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser

Помогите реализовать код

1. Находим регулярным выражением ссылку, типа: `<a href="http://hashcode.ru" target="_blank">Математика< /a>`.
2. Стираем target="_blank" и ставим пометочку, получаем `<a href="http://hashcode.ru"><!--mark-->Математика</a>`. - Сделано
3. Когда человек нажимает на ссылку перед открытием проверяем наличие пометочки и если пометка есть, то запрещаем открытие ссылки и создаём вкладку. - Не сделано
   Использую объект WebBrowser

Comment: У HTML нету возможностей потребовать от браузера открыть ссылку во вкладке, а не в новом окне. А чем вам не угодил `target="blank"`?

Comment: Я инфу нашел тут http://bit.pirit.info/forum/viewtopic.php?p=78534

Comment: @cas-live: эээ, это совсем не то. Ваша ссылка -- о ручной реализации браузера. Если уж вы сами реализуете браузер, вам надо честно и полностью распарсить тег `<a>`.

Comment: нет я использую конторол WebBrowser

Comment: @VladD, человек использует компонент WebBrowser из .NET Framework

Comment: @Niki-Timofe, Да

Comment: @cas-live: а, понятно. Тогда чем вам и вправду не угодил `target="_blank"`?

Comment: Я не понимаю как им воспользоваться

Comment: Про него бы сразу и спросили...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону события **`NewWindow`**, в нём как раз и можно создавать вторую вкладку и не нужно мудрить с метками.

---

Сначала возникнет событие **`NewWindow`**, в нём какой-нибудь переменной (OpenInNewTab) присвойте значение `True`, а потом в **`Navigaing`**, в `If`, если `OpenInNewTab = True`:

```
e.Cancel = True
```

создаёте новый объект **`WebBrowser`** и присваиваете его **`Uri`** значение **`Uri`** из "**`e`**"

---

##### P.S.

> И не забудьте потом вернуть значение OpenInNewTab на False ;)

Comment: О, ваш метод, кажется, лучше.

+1.

Comment: @Niki-Timofe, Можете код написать Нечего не выходит

Answer (score 1):

Короче, всё просто.

Во-первых, не трогайте `target="_blank"`, он там не просто так.

Во-вторых, подпишитесь на событие [`Navigating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx). По приходу события загляните в [`WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowsernavigatingeventargs.aspx) и проверьте целевую страницу/вкладку в [`TargetFrameName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowsernavigatingeventargs.targetframename.aspx). Если там `_blank`, создавайте новую вкладку в вашем UI.

Comment: Блин я настолько торможу Можете написать код
А так большое спасибо

Comment: @cas-live: извините, лень. Тем более, совет @Niki-Timofe лучше моего, отталкивайтесь от [`NewWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.newwindow.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

А если не добавлять метку, а заменять href на что-то вроде javascript:window.open('your url here')?

Comment: А при чём тут **`JavaScript`**?

Comment: Он может открыть IE